# Monotouch: "Unknown solution item type" after upgrading

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I recently just upgraded to Lion, upgraded my XCode install, and also upgraded to the latest MonoDevelop via the updating tool in the app. Once all the installations were done I tried to load in my project that I've been working on and get the following error:

"Error trying to load the project 'Users/filepathstuffs/project.csproj': Unknown solution item type."

The other thing I have noticed is that if I try to start a new project I don't even have the option anymore to start an iPhone or iPad project. Any help as to why this could have happened and what I can do to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
This is resolved. Poupou was correct in his assumption that the MonoTouch version was out of date. If upgrading to Lion your versions should look something like this

OSX: 10.7
Xcode: 4.1
MonoDevelop: 2.4.2
MonoTouch: 4.0.4.1

For some reason the MonoDevelop add-in manager didn't recognize that the MonoTouch add-in was out of date. I had to re-download and install from the website.

Comment: It looks like your MonoTouch addin is not up to date. Can you please edit your question and include all version numbers, e.g. MonoDevelop, Mono and MonoTouch (even xcode).

Comment: Thanks so much Poupou. The issue was that everything was up to date except for my MonoTouch add-in. It's weird that the add-in manager didn't recognize this and offer me to upgrade but alas the problem is resolved. 

For anyone else upgrading to Lion and in turn Xcode.. I would recommend updating MonoDevelop and re-installing the MonoTouch add-in because the add-in manager didn't recognize it was out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved. Poupou was correct in his assumption that the MonoTouch version was out of date. If upgrading to Lion your versions should look something like this

OSX: 10.7 Xcode: 4.1 MonoDevelop: 2.4.2 MonoTouch: 4.0.4.1

For some reason the MonoDevelop add-in manager didn't recognize that the MonoTouch add-in was out of date. I had to re-download and install from the website.